# How can I import an obj sequence into blender?

Tags: scripting, import, external-applications, obj

I have an obj sequence of a fluid simulation from Realflow. I've found a few tools that can import an obj sequence into blender, but most are outdated and don't work. Are there any scripts or plug-ins that can do that?

Comment: A better idea is to export it as pc2 or mdd, use a mesh cache modifier and load the sequence.

Comment: PC2 and MDD require the same number of vertices and faces per frame, fluid topology changes per frame, so neither of these formats are good.

Answer (score 3):

There is a patch for Blender allowing you to use RealFlow .bin files inside blender.

https://developer.blender.org/T41935

However it looks like the patch is no longer in development, due to alembic support coming very soon.

see: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2015-March/045025.html

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late, but I recently developed a Blender add-on for importing OBJ sequences (it also supports STL and PLY). It's called **Stop Motion OBJ**. It supports objects with changing topology (for example, your fluid simulation). Here's a [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?401143-Add-on-Stop-motion-OBJ-(OBJ-sequence-importer)) to the blenderartists thread where I announced it. Make sure to read through the README on the Github page for some important notes on how to use it.

Comment: Wow, how unfortunate we didn't have this back then. My question was for a project were we had to import all fluid-sim OBJs by hand and animate their visibility. It was tiresome. But I can see myself using this for future projects.

The project:
http://www.cgsociety.org/news/article/877/share-a-coke-with-arma

Answer (score 0):

Alembic support has been in an uncertain state in Blender. [See here for more details](https://developer.blender.org/D1783). Once it is supported then this will be solved.

Until then [this script](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?292968-AddOn-Import-OBJ-Sequence-As-Shape-Keys%28on-one-object%29&highlight=object%20sequence) is able to import OBJ sequences by using Shape keys